# Mocking axios receives empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, mocking

I'm looking to mock an axios call, but every time I do I get the mock return value as `{}`. I've tried to isolate just the `axios.get` and it seems that it's not mocking the output correctly.

```
    Expected: ObjectContaining {"data": "mocked expected"}
    Received: {}
```

Axios.test.js

```
const axios = require('axios');

jest.mock('axios')

it("fetches data", async () => {
    axios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
        data: "mocked received"
    });

    const url = '';
    
    const expected = {data: "mocked expected"};

    const out = axios.get(url)

    expect(out).toEqual(expect.objectContaining(expected));
});
```

Here's the terminal showing the issue.

[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWA33.png)

Comment: Use this [axios-mock-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter) package instead. Been using it for years and it's very DX friendly.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same result, I made a new react app, installed axios and axios-mock-adapter used axios-mock-adapter and still got the same error.

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Here's an [example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-testing-promises-bxntp) with a very simple asynchronous request to retrieve a todo. The thing to note is that promises are asynchronous and take time to resolve; therefore making expectations without letting the promise resolve will fail. So we'll `waitFor` the expectation to be true. You don't have to do it this way, but I find it the most DX friendly way of making assertions against async code (and works well with React hooks).